# Difference between sequential and conformational epitope

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology, bioinformatics, immunology

Is the difference only in its structure? Like conformational epitope has 3D structure while sequential has a linear structure?
(I have not studied biology since last 8 years and now I am going through it because I need it for my research. So if someone can describe it in simple language it would be very helpful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the difference is "only" in the 3D structure. This makes some differences when proteins change their shape; antibodies which recognize conformational epitopes are usually not well suited for lab work, as proteins are often denatured here.

The different epitopes are also called [linear epitopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_epitope) (for the sequential) and [discontinous epitope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformational_epitope) (for the conformational). Schematically this look like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice diagram. Where did you get it from ?

Comment: From a book: Immunology for Medical Students.